# C# - Convert all charts in excel spreadsheet to images

Tags: c#, excel

I need to be able to convert all charts in an excel spreadsheet to images programmatically (via c#),
I've tried `Aspose.cells` and it works perfectly, but i need a free alternative.

`EPplus` and other non-commercial libraries i know do not have the ability to do this,
and i'm in an web environment so I cannot use Office Interop.

My question is: is there any way I can programmatically read an .xlsx file and swap every chart it contains for an image of said chart, without depending on a paid library ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ClosedXML.Excel in nuget?

XLSX support

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
    worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
    worksheet.Cell("A2").FormulaA1 = "=MID(A1, 7, 5)";
    workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
}
```

source https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: The actual ClosedXML Library does not support Charts, i have found a "ClosedXML_Excel" in nuget, but it's actually an old version of Spire.Xls and has nothing to do with ClosedXML it also does not support .xlsx files

Comment: I don't understand how? Have you looked at github? https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/tree/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/Charts

Comment: That feature is still in development, searching the docs and examples, and messing arround with the actual library, i couldn't really find a way to convert charts to images, i did however found a way in Freespire.xls